# CAGradient using UIColor array

Tags: ios, swift, carousel, gradient

I have iCarousel set up to display a series of gradients.

```
    // Set gradient colours
    var gradientColours = [

    // First gradient
    UIColor(red:0.33, green:0.38, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.42, blue:0.42, alpha:1.0),

    //Second gradient
    UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.12, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.14, green:0.23, blue:0.33, alpha:1.0),

    // Third gradient
    UIColor(red:0.83, green:0.84, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.83, green:0.84, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0),

    // Fourth gradient
    UIColor(red:0.12, green:0.11, blue:0.09, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.56, green:0.05, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0),

    // Fifth gradient
    UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.75, blue:0.99, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.19, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)]

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let frontView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
    frontView.contentMode = .center

    frontView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    frontView.layer.masksToBounds = true;

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = frontView.bounds
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    gradient.colors = [gradientColours[index].cgColor, gradientColours[index+1].cgColor]

    frontView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    return frontView
```

The problem is, the first gradient is fine as it uses gradientColours[0] and gradientColours[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d1wz.png), but any other ones after that don't work as they use [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d1wz.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ihCe.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ihCe.png) and [3] and so on...

I feel as though this has an obvious answer but I cannot think of it at the moment...

Thanks for the help.

Edit:
Images for clarity:

First gradient works fine:

[image: First gradient, works fine]

First gradient works fine:
Second gradient takes first colour value from previous gradient:
[image: Second gradient, taking first value from previous gradient]

Comment: I feel like you're missing the last part of the code, is the last line just returning frontView?

Comment: Yes sorry `return frontView`

Comment: And if you were to print(index) would it increment as expected?

Comment: Actually, it increments as `0 3 2 1 4` do you know why this could be?

Comment: Could just be the style of carousel and the algorithm picking views to load based on position in 3D space rather than order. But if that index is incrementing then there should be no reason the gradient would be chosen wrong.

Comment: I ran your code and all the gradients work fine, i can see all 5 items in the carousel each with their own gradient.
How is your iCarousel configured?

Comment: What do you want this carousel to do? @w84u2cy

Comment: @DavidRees The gradients work fine for me as well, each item has a different one but, it seems that every item after the first grabs the wrong first colour to create the gradient. In the images I've attached see how the second item is using the first item's last gradient colour as its first. (I may not be explaining this well). If you set the colours of the first gradient to white you will see what I mean. The second item gradient will become half white.

Comment: @JaydeepVyas that actually does fix the issue. Thanks for that, big help.

Comment: @w84u2cy if it really helpful for you than please accept my answer

Comment: @JaydeepVyas playing around with the carousel I noticed a bug that after a while indexOfGradient colour would eventually get out of order. When first running the project it starts as `2 4 6 8 0` but then swiping through the carousel a few times and it prints as `8 0 2 4 6`. This makes the gradients out of order. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: It seems to be because every time there is interaction with the carousel, the function is run again, so eventually the values of indedOfGradientColor are wrong.

Comment: set indexOfGradientColor = 0 whenever you reload the carousel view

Comment: I ended up finding the carousel methods were the culprit and making the carousel reload. Specifically: `        
        else if (option == .fadeMin) {
            return -0.5;
        }
        
        else if (option == .fadeRange) {
            return 2.5;
        }
        
        else if (option == .fadeMax)   {
            return 0.5;
        }
` I'll find a fix for this. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Hey @JaydeepVyas , I've found that it seems to only work with a maximum of 7 carousel slides, or 14 values in the UIColor array. Is this right or have I gone wrong somewhere? When I use more than 14 it seems to reset the values when scrolling through, almost like it runs out of memory but I can't see how this would be the case.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with iCarousel more than your odd/even logic

Comment: @w84u2cy it might happen due to reuse of iCarousel cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solution for this by using simple odd/Even Logic see the below program

```
 import Foundation
var gradientColours = [

    // First gradient
    UIColor(red:0.33, green:0.38, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.42, blue:0.42, alpha:1.0),

    //Second gradient
    UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.12, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.14, green:0.23, blue:0.33, alpha:1.0),

    // Third gradient
    UIColor(red:0.83, green:0.84, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.83, green:0.84, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0),

    // Fourth gradient
    UIColor(red:0.12, green:0.11, blue:0.09, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.56, green:0.05, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0),

    // Fifth gradient
    UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.75, blue:0.99, alpha:1.0),
    UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.19, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)]

       var indexOfGradientColor = 0

     func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
     {
        let frontView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
        frontView.contentMode = .center

        frontView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
        frontView.layer.masksToBounds = true;

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = frontView.bounds
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        if (indexOfGradientColor%2 == 0)
        {
            gradient.colors = [gradientColours[indexOfGradientColor].cgColor, gradientColours[indexOfGradientColor+1].cgColor]

        }
        else
        { gradient.colors = [gradientColours[indexOfGradientColor+1].cgColor, gradientColours[indexOfGradientColor+2].cgColor]}
        if indexOfGradientColor < (gradientColours.count-2)
        {
                indexOfGradientColor += 2
        }
        else
        {
            indexOfGradientColor = 0
        }

        frontView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
        return frontView
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?

Comment: he has problem with index of gradient color so i have solved indexing problem